# How do I find the ETH value paid for a token in the Etherscan API?

Tags: transactions

I just started using the Etherscan API. My goal in Python is to find the ETH value spent in a transaction.

For example: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7ebae49604bcc6dc448af8e30d969a69fad20ca1da7944fff4ebb2cdcbdb4511

If I'm not mistaken in this process 2.31 ETH seems to have been spent for 91k tokens. I want to withdraw this spent ETH value.